# How to get list values inside dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following dictionary

```
{"api": {"results": 12, "seasons": [2008, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]}}
```

I need to extract values inside seasons key

```
[2008, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
```

and assign each list value to variable

```
var1 = 2008
var2= 2010 
etc
```

I am trying the following approach

```
a =  {"api": {"results": 12, "seasons": [2008, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]}}
for i in a["api"]["seasons"]:
    print(i)
```

After running above script i get an error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I also tried to extract values without specifying ["api"]["seasons"]

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

But output of this expression is only one digit per row. I understand that when inside list inside dictionary it have another rules for looping it. Can anyone guide me what i should read to better understand how i should loop in such cases

Comment: The posted code works fine for me. Tested with both Python 2 & 3.

Comment: @mario_sunny can you show me your output ?

Comment: Can you post your entire code? This code works. Maybe reinstall python

Comment: @НаглыйСпамер The output is the years `2008` - `2020` (inclusive), each on their own line.

Comment: @Laif i updated my post. Can you look at it again

Comment: If your last code prints the dates, it seems a is not the dict you show us, but directly the array of value

Comment: @mario_sunny I updated my post. Readit again please

Comment: @НаглыйСпамер Please post the broken code in one, congruent code block.

Comment: Just take a look : https://repl.it/repls/UnhealthyTanProjections and this is not a good idea to assign list values to independant variabls, leave them in the array

Comment: @azro i need to create separate objects from each list values to store them in database. Thank you for advise

Comment: This executes just fine for me as well. I would guess that the dictionary in this post is not what you are actually running your code against.

Comment: You don't need separate variables to create separate object in DB ;)

Comment: @НаглыйСпамер Please post unrelated issues as a separate question. Don't just edit your previous question and add more content. It confuses people into thinking you are still getting a `TypeError`.

Comment: @azro so strange but why i get this error when in your posted link its work pretty good i will try to check type of my variable a

Comment: @azro i checked type of variable a and it return me a string :) i get this variable a from opening file. I will try to  convert variable a from string to dictionary )

Answer (score 0):

The code works if youre just trying to get all to output on their own line. This will return the list on one line if thats preferred

```
a =  {"api": {"results": 12, "seasons": [2008, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]}}
print(a['api']['seasons'])
```

Comment: Your answer isn't what i need. I understand that i didnt describe what i need. I updated my post look at it again pls